# How to check which BLAS is in my Ubuntu system?

Tags: ubuntu, blas, openblas

In particular, I would like to know if xianyi's OpenBLAS has been installed. 
I work on several PCs and had it installed in several PCs over the past couple of years, but I lost track which were not installed with it. I need to know which PC has it and which doesn't This is how I installed it:

```
git clone git://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS
cd OpenBLAS
make FC=gfortran
sudo make PREFIX=/usr/local/ install
```

Note: I may have deleted the OpenBLAS directory, so it's not a reliable indicator. And I have no idea how to uninstall it, so I can't try installing it on every PC and then uninstall selectively (which is pretty cumbersome).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In include dir there is `openblas_config.h`
You can find openblas version there.
i.e.

```
grep OPENBLAS_VERSION /usr/local/include/openblas_config.h
```