# ImportError: No module named foxhound.utils.vis

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu, and python 2.7. Is there anybody help me overcome the following error?

> ImportError: No module named foxhound.utils.vis

which is caused by this line:

```
from foxhound.utils.vis import grayscale_grid_vis, unit_scale
```

I also did:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/jerome/bin/django-1.1/lib/python2.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

but no help!!

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you are trying to do?

Comment: You have to install `foxhound`.

Comment: @doru how can i install `foxhound`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already `foxhound` installed you should use:

```
from foxhound.vis import grayscale_grid_vis, unit_scale
```

because `vis` module is in the `foxhound` package and not in `foxhound.utils` (`utils` is also a module, not a package). See the `foxhound` structure [here](https://github.com/IndicoDataSolutions/Foxhound/tree/master/foxhound).

**Edit**

To install `foxhound`:

1. Download it and unzip it - [download link](https://github.com/IndicoDataSolutions/Foxhound).
2. In the terminal navigate into the unzipped folder (**Foxhound-master**).
3. There run

   `python setup.py install`

[More info](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) on installing python modules.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named foxhound.vis
`

Comment: i'm new in python. how to to install `foxhound` at all? (no documentation there)

Comment: thanks, now getting another error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/foxhound/vis.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib`

Comment: thanks, fixed by `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`

Comment: do you have any idea about this warning `OpenBLAS : Your OS does not support AVX instructions. OpenBLAS is using Nehalem kernels as a fallback, which may give poorer performance.`?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in an older version of **OpenBLAS**. it seems it's nothing critical [see here a small description](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/338).

Comment: I have installed a recent version of Ubuntu on virtualbox. How can I fix it?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186638/how-to-check-which-blas-is-in-my-ubuntu-system) to find the version of OpenBLAS you have.

Comment: I dont have `/usr/local/include/openblas_config.h` file. folder `/usr/local/include/` is empty for me.

Comment: Try in `/usr/local/lib/` there are python installed libs

Comment: See [here](https://hunseblog.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/installing-numpy-and-openblas/) how to install manually `numpy` with `OpenBlas`.