# How to install the png module in python

Tags: python

I'm kind of new to installing modules in python. I looked at this,
http://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html#png.Reader.asRGB8
But there is no download link.

It says "installation is trivial" but trivial means of little value or importance.
So I google "python png module download" but all the links are for 'pypng'
It says to use import png not import pypng.

So then I google how to install python modules, And I came across easy install. But easy install has its own installation also.

Is my best bet to use c# or c++ instead where it's much easier to download libraries?

Comment: [*"Just use `python setup.py install` or just copy the `code/png.py` file"*](http://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ca.html) - have you tried either of these methods? What happened? If you don't know where to get the files from, see https://github.com/drj11/pypng

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130126/importerror-no-module-named-foxhound-utils-vis/31132573#31132573) on how to install a python module. And this is the [download link for pypng](https://github.com/drj11/pypng/archive/master.zip).

Comment: I can't get it to install either. I am in the right directory. Getting a syntax error like the file does now exist. I would just copy the file mention but you did not say where to.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. I was doing it through the Python CL and should have done it with the Windows CMD.

Answer (score 59):

Try to print in command line/Terminal:

```
pip install pypng
```

and then import in your code as

```
import png
```

These are the same packages but it should be installed and be imported under different names

Comment: Thought that would be it.  :P  Typically the package name for a python library will be "pysomething", but the python namespace it puts its functions in will be just `something`.  Package names have to be unique against other png libraries for other languages, but python namespaces are already specific to python code.

Comment: I finally got pypng installed, But theres no examples on the documentation, How would I get the RGB8 values of each pixel individually? I don't really care about speed or preformance...

Comment: I guess this is another story:)  You should try to find something here https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ex.html and if not successful create new question

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8 and I can't import the png package. Even after a successful installation I keep receiving a this exception: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'png'`

Answer (score 6):

I encountered several errors while trying to install `pypng`.
I solved it with running it as ROOT:

```
$ sudo pip install pypng
```

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 20.04 this works:

1. install pip

   `sudo apt install python3-pip`
2. install png

   `sudo pip3 install pypng`
3. import library in code

   `import png`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, for conda users:

```
conda install -c eaton-lab pypng
```