# ImportError: No module named vis (Python )?

Tags: python, theano

Hello l tried to run my python code and the errors is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anelmad/Desktop/simulation/Theano-Tutorials-master/3_net.py", line 5, in <module>
    from foxhound.utils.vis import grayscale_grid_vis, unit_scale
ImportError: No module named vis**
```

knowing that l have correctly installed foxhound.

```
import theano

from theano import tensor as T

import numpy as np

from load import mnist

from foxhound.utils.vis import grayscale_grid_vis, unit_scale

from scipy.misc import imsave
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named foxhound.utils.vis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130126/importerror-no-module-named-foxhound-utils-vis)

Comment: For Windows Anaconda simple do: pip install keras-vis

Answer (score 1):

is Foxhound a scikit? if yes, it doe's not contains utils module. You can clone it on github https://github.com/IndicoDataSolutions/Foxhound

Comment: f rom foxhound.utils.vis import grayscale_grid_vis, unit_scale                                                                                          error                                                                                                                        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/lib/_util.py:35: DeprecationWarning: Module scipy.linalg.blas.fblas is deprecated, use scipy.linalg.blas instead
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named vis

Answer (score 0):

I have met with the same problem. from foxhound vis import grayscale_grid_vis is enough. And I just comment out the other part. And the program works well. It seems that the module is not used.